# Python code working in REPL but not when imported/executed as a module

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

So I have a module that's part of my Flask web app that contains the database connection. It's pretty simple.

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, MetaData
import os
from sqlalchemy.schema import Table, Column

host = os.environ.get("DATABASE_PORT_5432_TCP_ADDR") or "localhost"
port = os.environ.get("DATABASE_PORT_5432_TCP_PORT") or "5432"
url = host + ":" + port

engine = create_engine('postgresql+pg8000://postgres:password@%s/empathy' % url) 
_meta = MetaData(bind=engine)
_meta.reflect(views=True, schema="biomart")
```

If I run `python` and copy these commands into the REPL, it executes fine, and I can run _meta.tables to get a list of tables in my database.

However if I run `python database.py` or simply `import database` in the REPL, this causes an error: `'communication error', error(111, 'Connection refused')`.

How can a connection be refused when the code is in a module, but it's fine when it's being run in the REPL? Are there any differences between these two situations I can use to debug my code?

The only other piece of information is that this is all in a docker container, and that's why I'm checking for the environment variables at the top. But I don't see this being an issue.

Comment: As a side note, you really don't want to write `os.environ.get(name) or defvalue` unless you actually want to prevent people from explicitly setting a variable to the empty string. Normally, you just use `os.environ.get(name, defvalue)`, which properly treats the empty string as different from not being set at all.

Comment: Meanwhile, are the env variables actually the same in the docker container as in the REPL? (Have you tried `print`ing them out?) And are the Python and `sqlalchemy` module versions the same?

Comment: Finally, does the Docker engine have a transparent network configuration (or explicitly the same configuration as the host OS), or is it maybe getting in the way? (If you just `nc host:port` from inside the container and from outside, do you get the same result?)

Comment: Thanks for that first tip, I didn't know environ.get had another argument. Yes the environment variables are the same and correct in both cases because I'm running both of these cases in the same docker container. That's why I don't think it's a docker issue